# JQuery SimpleDialog2 close event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

How do I capture a close event for the SimpleDialog2 plugin? In other words, if the user clicks on the X on the dialog, how can I get a function to fire? (As you can see below, I have the headerClose property set to true.)

```
$(document).simpledialog2({
    mode: 'blank',
    headerText: 'Change Status',
    headerClose: true,
    ...
```

Comment: Use the `callbackClose` callback? Ex: `callbackClose: function(){`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `callbackClose: function () {....` for this